# FULL JOIN doesn't work in two ways

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to write a FULL JOIN statement in SQL but it doesn't work as fine as I would like.
Here is my full statement

```
 SELECT 
        t.tacNom, bh.heuresChiffrees, 
        SUM(ISNULL(heures,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(minutes,0)/60) as HeuresRealisee, (ISNULL(bh.heuresChiffrees,0) - (SUM(ISNULL(heures,0)) + (SUM(ISNULL(minutes,0))/60))) as Solde,
        (SUM(DISTINCT minutes)%60) as Soldeminutes
    FROM tbl_BalanceHeures bh
            FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_HeuresTimbrage_new ht ON  ht.idProjet = bh.proIdProjetExterne 
            AND ht.idxTache = bh.idxTache 
            AND ht.idxDep= bh.idxDepartement
            INNER JOIN tbl_Taches t on t.idTache = bh.idxTache
            WHERE proIdProjetExterne = '00Z 000104' AND bh.idxDepartement = 184
    GROUP BY  t.tacNom ,bh.heuresChiffrees
```

Here are the result of the statement

```
idTache heuresChiffrees HeuresRealisee  Solde
332              25                 0        25  
330              50                 0        50
327             100                42    58
331             100                23    77
```

Here are the records in my table tbl_Balance and the statement

```
select t.idTache, bh.heuresChiffrees
from tbl_BalanceHeures bh
INNER JOIN tbl_Taches t on t.idTache = bh.idxTache
WHERE proIdProjetExterne= '00Z 000104' AND bh.idxDepartement = 184

idTache heuresChiffrees
330      50
331     100
327     100
332      25
```

Here are the records in tbl_HeuresTimbrage and the statement

```
 Select t.idTache, ht.heures as heuresRealisees
 From tbl_HeuresTimbrage_new ht
  INNER JOIN tbl_Taches t on t.idTache = ht.idxTache
 WHERE idProjet= '00Z 000104' AND ht.idxDep = 184

  idTache   heuresRealisees
    327               32
    331               23
    327               10
    334               4
```

So, In my FULL JOIN Statement I am expected to find

```
IdTache  heuresChiffrees Heures Realisees
327       100           10
330       50          NULL (or 0)
331       100           23
332       25          NULL (or 0)
334     NULL(or 0)    4
```

I've tried to put my WHERE clause in the Full JOIN but it doesn't work

Comment: Your expected and actual results bear no relation to your posted query, so it is quite confusing to understand the problem. Please can you post your actual query, actual table schemas, and actual data. You can use http:\\sqlfiddle.com to post a runnable version demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because of your `WHERE` clause. It is acting on the **joined result**, and so if the `A` side is null, it will eliminate those rows.

You can change it to be a condition of the join instead, as so:

```
FROM A 
FULL OUTER JOIN B  
ON  B.idProjet = A.proIdProjetExterne 
AND B.idxTache = A.idxTache 
AND B.idxDep= A.idxDepartement
AND A.proIdProjetExterne =  'xxx' 
AND A.idxDepartement = 184
```

However, without seeing your actual data or schema, this is a bit of a guess...

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information - it's unreadable in a comment...